# vim: have Ctrl+right stop at EOL (just after last character of last word)

Tags: vim

In windoze, when I use Ctrl+right, it moves word to word, and if I get to the end of the line, it stops on the last character of the last word + 1 (maybe that's the EOL character, not sure).  In vim, when I reach the last word using Ctrl+right and hit it again, it skips the EOL and goes to the next word on the next line.

How would I get vim to follow the same method windows uses?  Do I need to write a script for that?

Comment: "looking for quicker movement in insert mode" .. you are fighting against the modes. movement is done in "normal" mode, so just   escape shift-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Escape</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to append (at the EOL). If you fight vim and try to do all your movement in insert mode, vim will win.

Comment: That's what I usually do because Euro-keyboards have `$` in a difficult place.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to change this, but did you know that, being in command mode, `$` brings you to the EOL?

Comment: yep, Im looking for quicker movement in insert mode.  thanks though!

Comment: Then no idea, except for the `end` key

Comment: +1 for the `end` key. Worked by default for me on every Vim/Win system I've used in insert and edit modes.

Comment: end might work..  id have to write a script though to mimic windows behavior (if word is last word on line, then use end instead of <C+Right> when I hit key sequence "foobar").

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

```
<C-o> $
```

while in insert mode. `<C-o>` allows you to make one normal-mode command and you stay in insert mode.